# Questions regarding custom multiclass metrics (Keras)

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, metrics

could anyone explain how to write a custom multiclass metrics for Keras? I tried to write custom metric but encountered some issue. Main problem is I am not familiar with how tensor works during training (I think it is called Graph mode?). I am able to create confusion matrix and derived F1 score using NumPy or Python list.

I printed out the y-true and y_pred and tried to understand them, but the output was not what I expected:

Below is the function I used:

```
def f1_scores(y_true,y_pred):

    y_true = K.print_tensor(y_true, message='y_true = ')
    y_pred = K.print_tensor(y_pred, message='y_pred = ')
    print(f"y_true_shape:{K.int_shape(y_true)}")
    print(f"y_pred_shape:{K.int_shape(y_pred)}")

    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)

    gt = K.argmax(y_true_f)
    pred = K.argmax(y_pred_f)

    print(f"pred_print:{pred}")
    print(f"gt_print:{gt}")

    pred = K.print_tensor(pred, message='pred= ')
    gt = K.print_tensor(gt, message='gt =')
    print(f"pred_shape:{K.int_shape(pred)}")
    print(f"gt_shape:{K.int_shape(gt)}")

    pred_f = K.flatten(pred)
    gt_f = K.flatten(gt)

    pred_f = K.print_tensor(pred_f, message='pred_f= ')
    gt_f = K.print_tensor(gt_f, message='gt_f =')
    print(f"pred_f_shape:{K.int_shape(pred_f)}")
    print(f"gt_f_shape:{K.int_shape(gt_f)}")

    conf_mat = tf.math.confusion_matrix(y_true_f,y_pred_f, num_classes = 14)

    """
    add codes to find F1 score for each class
    """

    # return an arbitrary number, as F1 scores not found yet.
    return 1
```

The output at when epoch 1 just started:

```
y_true_shape:(None, 256, 256, 14)
y_pred_shape:(None, 256, 256, 14)
pred_print:Tensor("ArgMax_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)
gt_print:Tensor("ArgMax:0", shape=(), dtype=int64)
pred_shape:()
gt_shape:()
pred_f_shape:(1,)
gt_f_shape:(1,)
```

Then for the rest of the steps and epochs were similar as below:

```
y_true =  [[[[1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   [1 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
   ...

y_pred =  [[[[0.0889623 0.0624801107 0.0729747042 ... 0.0816219151 0.0735477135 0.0698677748]
   [0.0857798532 0.0721047595 0.0754121244 ... 0.0723947287 0.0728530064 0.0676521733]
   [0.0825942457 0.0670698211 0.0879610255 ... 0.0721599609 0.0845924541 0.0638583601]
   ...

pred=  1283828
gt = 0
pred_f=  [1283828]
gt_f = [0]
```

Why is pred a number instead of a list of numbers with each number represents index of class? Similarly, why is pred_f is a list with only one number instead of list of indices?

And for gt (and gt_f), why is the value 0? I expect them to be list of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like `argmax()` simply uses the flattened `y`.
You need to specify which axis you want `argmax()` to reduce. Probably it's the last one, in your case 3. Then you'll get `pred` with a shape `(None, 256, 256)` containing integer between 0 and 13.
Try something like this: `pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=3)`
[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax) is the documentation for tensorflow argmax. (But I'm not sure if you're using exactly that, since I can not see what K is imported as)

Comment: Thanks! I double checked my code and indeed ```y``` were flattened before ```argmax()```. There were two lines of code(flatten) which I thought were not used during my test but I was wrong. I updated the original question, adding the ```flatten()``` before ```argmax()```, so that the code and the output are consistent.

Comment: I ran the code again after removing the ```flatten()``` before ```argmax()```, and it output list of indices, which was reasonable :) But I am sorry I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation yet.